# I am new to databases and I want to create a recipes database

Tags: sqlite, database-design, database-connection

I have a question about how to implement the primary keys and foreign keys in a `Recipe` database in each table. I am also interested to know if it is acceptable to have many tables associated with one foreign as I have with the many relationships in this table.

[Here is my database desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UulmR.png)

How to design primary key and foreign key. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use an identity column for your primary key. This way you will have and auto increment key and you don't have to worry about the other values in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
column1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
column2 datatype,
column3 datatype,
.....
columnN datatype,
);
```

Something like this would give you the AUTOINCREMENT ability.

Yes you can have multiple tables associated with one foreign key.

For example lets take a university and students.

Students
Student ID(Primary Key) | Name
25 | Mary
32 | Joe

Lets say Mary wants to take biology and Joe wants to take chemistry

Class
Class_ID (Primary Key)| Student_ID(Foreign Key) | ClassName | ClassCode
65 | 25 | Biology | SCEN 1014
75 | 32 | Chemistry | CHEM 1014

Then lets also say Mary wants to join the Cheer Squad and Job wants to be a gymnast.

Extracurricular
Activity_ID(Primary Key)| Student_ID(Foreign Key) | ActivityName
23 | 32 | Gymnastics
44 | 25 | Cheer

This example may be a little cryptic but the primary key in the student table is a foreign key in the classes table and extra curricular table. I hope that answers your question.